# delete element using remove() while clicking and pressing a key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a delete mode that the user can enter by pressing a certain key (Im using the key "enter" for now e.which == 13 checks if the key pressed is enter in the below sample)

```
var checker = 1;
$(document).keypress(function (e) {

    if (e.which == 13 && checker == 1) {
        checker = 2;
        alert("entered delete mode");
        $(".element1").click(function (e) {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }
    else if (e.which == 13 && checker == 2) {
        checker = 1;
        alert("exited delete mode");

        $(".element1").each(function (i, e) {
            $(this).off("click", "**");
        });
    };

});
```

So basically when the user presses enter I check if we are in the delete mode already, if not (checker ==1) we enter it and I add a function on click() for objects with class ".element1"

If the user is in not in delete mode (checker==2), I try to remove the click method.

But for some reason this part does not work.

Thank you all.

**EDIT**

I also tried to add .click to the .element class: (this way in my mind it should've deleted the element when I hover and press enter)

```
     $(.element1)
     .hover(function (e) {
                                    var deletable = $(this);
                                    $(document).keypress(function (e) {
                                        if (e.which == 13) {
                                            deletable.remove();
                                        }
                                    });
                                });
```

but whenever I press enter it just deletes all .elements

Any way works for me.

Comment: why doesn't it work? any errors in console, need to be more specific than `for some reason this part does not work`

Comment: Technically you are removing the element from the DOM. You are not deleting it.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs no errors, simply nothing happens and I can still delete the objects by clicking.

Comment: I think what he is trying to do has been solved in my answer--the problem is that it was still removing the element if you clicked on it after you exited delete mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a second argument on the `.off()`. Fixed code:

```
var checker = 1;
$(document).keypress(function (e) {

    if (e.which == 13 && checker == 1) {
        checker = 2;
        alert("entered delete mode");
        $(".element1").click(function (e) {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }
    else if (e.which == 13 && checker == 2) {
        checker = 1;
        alert("exited delete mode");

        $(".element1").off("click");
    };

});
```

I also got rid of the second `.each()`, as suggested in the comments (it wasn't necessary).

Comment: Is the `each` really required for `off()`?

Comment: If he had more than one element with that class I am pretty sure -- let me check actually.

Comment: No you don't! I added this in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using on/off like this and not removing the element:

```
var checker = 1;
$(document).keypress(function (e) {

    if (e.which == 13 && checker == 1) {
        checker = 2;
        alert("entered delete mode");
        $(".element1").on('click', function (e) {
            // handle click
        });
    }
    else if (e.which == 13 && checker == 2) {
        checker = 1;
        alert("exited delete mode");

        $(".element1").off('click', '**');
    };

});
```

Comment: I dont see how that would change anything given the provided snippet.

Comment: `.click(arg2)` is an alias for `.on("click", arg2)`--his should work.